# Stata: How to name a variable with a value

Tags: stata

I would like to create a variable that takes a name of a value in particular cell. For example my data set looks like this

```
var1 count
xx   1
xc   2
xv   3
xj   4
```

I would like to create 4 new variables that take names from the values of the variable `var1`. For example, three variables would be `xx xc xv xj`. I understand `reshape` would do this but in my case I don't want to use `reshape`. I tried the code below

```
forvalues i =1/4{
local d var1  count ==`i'
gen xx_`d'= . 
}
```

Comment: Very unclear. What would these variables contain? What is the relevance of the count to your question? Your code would fail, if only because second time round the loop the variable `xx_d` already exists. Check out `help separate`.

Comment: Why 4/8? Relevance to example? Is `counter` supposed to be the same as `count`?

Comment: @NickCox Sorry for the confusion and the mistakes in my post. Firstly the variables will contain arbitrary values. Secondly count is calculated using *_n*. Hope this clears the confusion

Comment: Sorry, that clarifies little for me. "will contain arbitrary values" could hardly be more obscure. Count calculated using `_n`: means nothing to me either. I don't get what you want.

Comment: @NickCox for now I want the variable values to be *.*.  I would like to create a set of variables that would have names == values of var1. The actual value of each created variable should be ==.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sounds bizarre, but this I think I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fail unless the variable looked at, here `var1`, is a string variable and every distinct value of the variable used could be a new and legal variable name. I've not tried to make the code resistant to failures of the assumptions.

```
levelsof var1, local(levels) 
foreach v of local levels { 
    gen `v' = . 
}
```

It's not the question, but it's hard to see how this could be useful.

Comment: The variable values are indeed sting and contain no illegal characters. Thank you very much